# How to delete and put some data on complex json file with jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a problem, I wrote a function for printing message data from a JSON file, but I do not know how to remove message data with specific id and reply on message  to sender? Do I use only javascript or I have to use PHP? Can somebody help me?

My data.json file:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":"2146",
         "from":{
            "id":"234",
            "name":"Alan Ford"
         },
         "to":{
            "id":"4949",
            "name":"Eric Owens"
         },
         "type":"1",
         "replyto":"0",
         "date_sent":"1344359836",
         "date_read":"0",
         "subject":"test",
         "message":"test inbox",
         "message_formatted":"test inbox",
         "date_sent_formatted":{
            "id":1196,
            "timestamp":1344297600,
            "month":8,
            "day":7,
            "year":2012,
            "week":32,
            "dayid":3,
            "weekday":"Tue",
            "mname":"Aug",
            "formatted":"Aug 7, 2012"
         },
         "date_read_formatted":[

         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"2048",
         "from":{
            "id":"234",
            "name":"Alan Ford"
         },
         "to":{
            "id":"8110",
            "name":"Event"
         },
         "type":"1",
         "replyto":"0",
         "date_sent":"1343248577",
         "date_read":"0",
         "subject":"afd",
         "message":"asdfads",
         "message_formatted":"asdfads",
         "date_sent_formatted":{
            "id":1184,
            "timestamp":1343260800,
            "month":7,
            "day":26,
            "year":2012,
            "week":30,
            "dayid":5,
            "weekday":"Thu",
            "mname":"Jul",
            "formatted":"Jul 26, 2012"
         },
         "date_read_formatted":[

         ]
      }
    ]
}
```

My jquery file:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON('public/js/data.json', function(json){


        var msg = json.data

        for ( i = 0; i < msg.length; i++ ) {


                    var  content =  '<li>';
                         content += '<span class="left">' + msg[i].from.name +'</span>';
                         content += '<span class="right">'+ msg[i].date_sent_formatted.formatted +'</span>';
                         content += '<p>' + msg[i].subject + '</p>';
                         content += '<p>' + msg[i].message + '</p>';
                         content += '<button>Replay</button>';
                         content += '<button>Delete</button>';
                         content += '</li>';


                    $('.content').append(content);
        }

    });


});


function delete_message(id){


}

function reply_message(id, sender){

}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You have to use PHP or Other File Handling programming language to actually modify the file. And as for the Message Sending part you need server side programming language to perform that task too.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: here's a fiddle of this question, just trying to help: http://jsfiddle.net/ar285p42/  OP, is the ouput ok?

Comment: Yes, output is correct...

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio Yes, output is correct... but I have to use php and jquery, and i trying to figure out... this is just for my learning process :-)

Comment: @stori87 here is an updated fiddle showing hot to remove ("delete") a message ( "<li>" ) from your list: http://jsfiddle.net/ar285p42/1/ does it help?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio Thank you, it help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You will try this :

First parse the json :

```
Use var dataArray = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
```

Then remove your data :

```
There are several ways. The splice method is the most versatile:

data.items.splice(1, 3); // Removes three items starting with the 2nd,
                         // ("Witches of Eastwick", "X-Men", "Ordinary People")
```

[Remove data from json 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310623/remove-item-from-json-array-using-its-name-value)
[Remove data from json 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538269/adding-removing-items-from-json-data-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can try underscorejs, and use findWhere function like this

```
function reply(id,aReply){
the_message = _.findWhere(data.data, {id: id});
the_message.message = aReply;
//do your thing
```

}